# Popping a value from one stack and Pushing to another using C

Tags: arrays, c, stack

I am currently learning some C and have created a basic connect 4 game. I am trying to now implement a undo/redo function, I have created a stack using an array basically saving every move made by each player. I can push moves and pop moves to and from the stack, so the undo part I can get working, the redo part is where I'm struggling. I am wondering if I can create a temp stack and when I Pop from my master stack I can push to this temp one? In my head this will then allow me to redo moves as well.

I can't find any decent examples that explain this very well and am just looking for a point in the right direction if anyone has created something similar? Also if there is a more efficient method I'm completely open to that also.

Thank you in advance

<>

```
    void push2(int y)
{
  if(top2 == MAX_SIZE2 -1) { // stack full case.
        printf("Error: stack is full\n");
        return;
    }
    
    top2 = top2 + 1;
    stack2[top2] = y;
    //A[++top] = y;
}

      // Pop operation to remove an element from top of first stack.
void pop()
{
    push2(top); //add to second stack 
    
    if(top == -1) { // If stack is empty, throw error.
        printf("Error: No items to pop\n");
        return;
    }
     
    //x = stack[top];
    //top = top - 1;
    
    top--;
}
```

Comment: You've implemented one stack, but don't know how to implement a second one?

Comment: So I know how to implement a second one, I guess what im asking is, when I pop() do i then call my second push() function to add the value to the second stack and vice versa for putting back to the original?

Comment: Why not try it, and if you have a problem with it, ask for help?

Comment: Thank you Scott, I have tried to implement and getting an error: "too few arguments for call". I have edited the post with the code i have tried. Is this because when I'm using push2() in the pop im not assigning the value to a variable so therefore not pushing anything at all?

Comment: If you aren't pushing anything, why do you need to call `push2` at all?

Comment: So i do want to push something. I want to basically record each move made by the players and save them into stack1, then when a player wants to undo a move, it pops from stack1 and pushes to stack2, essentially that's what I'm trying to do in the code above. In my head that means i can save the undone moves and this will help with the redo function because i can then pop the stack2 moves back into stack1 if that makes sense?

Comment: If you want to push something, why don't you identify what it is in the call to `push2`?

Comment: I tried to push the top value from the number 1 stack by doing push2(top). So i put in the combination 1,4,3,7 and then called pop() hoping it would pop 7 from my original to the second stack. But for some reason it gets rid of 7 before pushing to the second stack so im left with:

Stack: 1,4,3
Stack2: 3

I've edited the pop() above to show the code.

Comment: Please, post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think changing `push2(top);` to `push2(stack[top]);` might help.

Your `top` variable seems to be an index variable, therefore it makes only sense in the context of `stack`

Comment: Thank you so much this has worked. Got it adding and removing from both stacks now!